# Android w/ Eclipse Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting this error when I try to build under Android w/ Eclipse IDE.

`com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

I understand it has to do with Java version mismatch.

I started to get this recently after I updated some SDK files.

I'm trying to compile under 1.7

I installed jre 1.8 and added to IDE installed jre - but it's not showing up under the compiler list for the project - only up to 1.7.

The only thing I can think of is some Google sdk library file is compiled under 1.8. Is there a way to tell which one and/or is there a way to downgrade some of these libraries (e.g. Google Play Services).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also install JDK 1.8 (JRE doesn't include compiler).

Comment: I'm a dumbass - thanks! But I'd like to stay with 1.6 (current env) - is there a way to identify which module and/or download to an earlier sdk lib.

Comment: I highly suggest upgrading your jdk - you don't have to change anything codewise and you'll be stuck with outdated libraries and tools.

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND: The problem was I had to edit the eclipse ini file and upgrade to java8. I asssume some eclipse library got updated...not sure.

Answer (score 0):

"SOLUTION FOUND: The problem was I had to edit the eclipse ini file and upgrade to java8. I asssume some eclipse library got updated...not sure." -> This worked to me